# Trim property in get method

Tags: c#

At the moment I'm doing something like:

```
public virtual String zipcodeRaw { get; set; }
public virtual String zipcode {
    get
    {
        return zipcodeRaw.Trim();
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can do something like:

```
public virtual String zipcode {
    get
    {
        return zipcode.Trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: That will cause ur stack to blow up

Comment: Why do you want to do it the second way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That would give you an infinite loop since zipcode refers to itself. However, properties are just public accessors and modifiers for a private variable.  You could certainly do:

```
private string _zipcode;

public virtual string zipcode {
   get { return _zipcode.Trim(); }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd move the .Trim() to the setter: usually you will read the value more often than write it. Also guard against a null value.